# Visual Studio: how can I debug a remote application which is running as root?

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have an application running on an Ubuntu instance in GCP. The program opens a server on port 80 so it has to be run as root.

I've setup my SSH connection successfully, but when I attempt to connect the process remotely I get the error:

> Failed to attach to process: The .NET debugger has insufficient
> privileges to debug this process

[image]

I tried to start `vsdbg` with `sudo .vs-debugger/vs2022/vsdbg`, but I got the same error.

How can I attach to this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround with a hack.

`cd ~/.vs-debugger/vs2022/`

`mv vsdbg vsdbg.original`

`nano vsdbg`

Copy this into that file:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ~/.vs-debugger/vs2022/vsdbg.original $@
```

Et voila.